# using entity in other intent in dialogflow

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In intent A, under 'Training Phrases', I added a user expression.
eg.`@sys.given-name:given-name` So that Google Assistant is able to read any name given by user.

In intent B, i added user phone number. I want Google Assistant to print out my given name which i previously mention in intent A and phone number.

eg..

```
You name is $given-name and your number is $phone-number.
```

but it can't seem to print out the given-name. Any suggestions on what should be added?

Answer (score 2):

You can set an output-context in intent A, then use that context in intent 2 to print the given-name.

For example: in intent 1 you will set `name` as output context, then in intent 2 you will respond with -
`Your name is #name.given-name and your number is $phone-number.`